# how to customize email template with header and footer of site?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am sending a mail to users related to product now i want to design it according to site like header and footer should be site. and middle content will customize. What is the process for doing this?

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

find **header.html** and **footer.html** files in `app/locale/en_US/templates/email/html` folder.

using these files you can customize header and footer of your email templates.

Comment: i want to send email template with html content i mean.. according to site ..i had create a html on app/locale/en_us/templates/email/html but whats next how to add it with my mail function??